# How does PHP read text files?

Tags: php, integer

I have a simple number in a text document, and I get it out by `$text_data = fread($file_handle, 2)` (first two bytes, where the num should be - less than 10).

At one point, I check if the file is "OK" by trying to determine if the read value is either integer outside 0 = to N interval, or integer:

```
if (!is_int($text_data) OR $text_data < 0 OR $text_data > MAXIMUM_TRIES)
```

But it doesn't work!

This `IF` returns `TRUE` whatever the value from TXT file, and I don't know what to do next.

Any ideas?

Comment: Time for some basic debugging! Do `echo $text_data;`. What does it display? What's the value of `MAXIMUM_TRIES`? If you split the `if` into three separate phrases (`if (!is_int($text_data) ) { echo 'is_int'; }  if( $text_data < 0 ) { echo "< 0"; } etc`) which ones return true?

Comment: `$text_data < 0` <-- what do you expect to happen here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string containing a number that could be parsed to an integer, is not yet an integer, but still a string. You need to cast it to an integer by using `intval()` for example.

You could try `is_numeric()` in stead of `is_int()`

```
var_dump(is_int(10)); // true
var_dump(is_int("10")); // false
var_dump(is_numeric("10")); // true
var_dump(is_int(intval("10"))); // true
```

So what I am saying is, just before doing your `if()`, first do this:

```
$text_data = intval($text_data);
```

Comment: As an alternative you can use plain type casting in recently modern php versions: `text_data = (int) $text_data;`. Most people find this easier to read and it works for all types.

Answer (score 1):

`This IF returns TRUE whatever the value from TXT file`

Just because your `$text_data` variable is always a string value. Then `!is_int($text_data)` can not be false.

You need to change this line:

```
if (!is_int($text_data) OR $text_data < 0 OR $text_data > MAXIMUM_TRIES)
```

to

```
$number = (int)$text_data; //if $text_data is not a number, $text will be 0
if ( $number !== 0 && ($number < 0 || $number > MAXIMUM_TRIES))
```

Comment: Do I also need to check condition is the variable number at all, or this should suffice? This condition has a purpose of truncating the file if it gets corrupted somehow. I am concerned if the condition with (int) only with interval will be sufficient to trigger the FALSE statement? (Thanks a lot!!)

Comment: I've edited my answer to check whether your string value is a number.